# GraphQL: I need nested AND with OR operators inside to filter my data

Tags: graphql, nestjs, typegraphql

```
query books($search: String, $country_id: Int) {
  books(where: {
            and: [
              {country_id: { eq: $country_id }},
              { or: [
                  {id: { like: $search }},
                  {name: { like: $search }}]
              }
            ]
  })
}
```

The red line locates on OR operator.
The goal is to filter by country_id and include the "search" value to filter by either. The example I showed does not work. Error message here:
`"message": "Field \"or\" is not defined by type YOUR_TYPE,`
that means it does not recognize nested operators.

I expect to use complex nested operator combinations by GraphQL to have some conditions as required and some as not.

Answer (score 0):

No need to make nested operators. This makes it work:

```
books(where: 
      {country_id: { eq: $country_id },
      or: [
        {id: { like: $search }},
        {name: { like: $search }}
      ]}
    ) {
```